# How to differentiate between click and drag/drop event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with element which is both draggable and also has a click event.

```
$('.drag').mousedown(function() {
    //...
});

$('.class').click(function() {
    //...
)};

<div class="drag class"></div>
```

When I drag and drop the element, the click event gets fired, too. How to prevent that?

Comment: http://blog.lysender.com/2010/04/jquery-draggable-prevent-click-event/ will might help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also you could probably do something with the mousemove and mousedown events together to disable the click event:

```
var dragging = 0;

$('.drag').mousedown(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
       dragging = 1;
    });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    dragging = 0;
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});

$('.class').click(function() {
    if (dragging == 0){
       // default behaviour goes here
    }
    else return false;
)};
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do that by stopping the propagation on the mousedown event.

```
$('.drag').mousedown(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You may have to make sure that this event is attached before the click event though.

Comment: This disabled dragging in my case. I'm using a slick carousel that needs to be draggable, but also able to click slides in it.

Comment: use that event will disable draggable

Answer (score 1):

In my case selected answer didn't worked. So here is my solution which worked properly(may be useful for someone):

```
    var dragging = 0;
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        dragging = 0;
        $(document).mousemove(function(){
           dragging = 1;
        });
    });

    $('.class').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (dragging == 0){
            alert('it was click');
        }
        else{
            alert('it was a drag');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if the drag event is registered prior to click event then the problem described will not happen. Here is an example code:

This code create the mentioned problem:

```
        var that = this;
        var btnId = "button_" + this.getId();
        var minView = $("<div>", {"id":btnId, style:"position:absolute; top:"
            + this.options.style.top + ";left:" + this.options.style.left + ";border:1px solid gray;padding:2px"});
        minView.html(this.getMinimizedTitle());

        minView.click(function expendWidget(event) {
            $("#" + btnId).remove();
            that.element.css({"left":that.options.style.left, "right":that.options.style.right});
            that.element.show();
        });

        minView.draggable();
        minView.on("drag", this.handleDrag.bind(this));

        this.element.parent().append(minView);
```

this code does not create the problem:

```
        var that = this;
        var btnId = "button_" + this.getId();
        var minView = $("<div>", {"id":btnId, style:"position:absolute; top:"
            + this.options.style.top + ";left:" + this.options.style.left + ";border:1px solid gray;padding:2px"});
        minView.html(this.getMinimizedTitle());

        minView.draggable();
        minView.on("drag", this.handleDrag.bind(this));

        minView.click(function expendWidget(event) {
            $("#" + btnId).remove();
            that.element.css({"left":that.options.style.left, "right":that.options.style.right});
            that.element.show();
        });
        this.element.parent().append(minView);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, but you should alway remember, that user can move mouse slightly during the click and don't notice that. So he'd think hi clicked and you – that he dragged