# Detect click without selection?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a little alert box. I want users to be able to click it to dismiss it, *but* if they click and drag to select the message off it, I don't want it to disappear on them.

The `.on('click'` event seems to fire as soon as the mouse button is released, even if they've made a selection, or waited several seconds.

How can I detect this kind of click?

Comment: still not clear what you are trying to explain..

Comment: Try looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283193/how-to-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-drop-event

Comment: @Mark you have good scor on jquery and javascript and reputation as well it seems like you posted accidently?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to distinguish between drag and click. Which is a fair question.

Comment: @A.B I'm capable of coming up with a solution to most of the questions I ask, but there are many ways to go about any one problem. I like seeing different approaches and drawbacks so that I can best decide how to tackle it.

Comment: @Mark great ,was just amazed by you current performance on SO

Answer (score 4):

What I did to get around this issue is

```
$(document).on("click", ".my-clickable-class", function(){
    //
    ///don't fire if the user was selecting something
    //
    if(window.getSelection().toString()!="")
        return;
    //do click stuff
});
```

It just checks if the user made a text selection. If they did, don't perform the click behavior.

Comment: Not bad, but getSelection is IE9+

Comment: Looks like you might be able to use the `document.selection` object in IE<9, but I am not familiar with how that object works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to detect if the `mouse moved` while the mouse was down check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggqo4nt7/

```
var isMouseDown = false;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
var oldMouseX;
var oldMouseY;

$("div").bind("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(!isMouseDown) {
        oldMouseX = e.pageX;
        oldMouseY = e.pageY;
    }
    else {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    }
});

$("div").bind("mousedown", function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
});

$("div").bind("mouseup", function() {
   isMouseDown = false;
    if(mouseX != oldMouseX && mouseY != oldMouseY) {
      alert("Ive been clicked and I moved");   
    }
    else {
      alert("Ive been clicked");   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with, based on [Travis' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451432/65387) but a little simpler:

```
var mouseMove = false;
$item.on('mousemove', function() {
    mouseMove = true;
}).on('mousedown', function() {
    mouseMove = false;
}).on('mouseup', function() {
    if(!mouseMove) {
        fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I'm just hoping that my users are dexterous enough to click without dragging even a single pixel.